# Only count up every second time

Tags: count, while-loop

How do I only count up every second time in my while condition?
I only know how to count up everytime like this " $c_id=++$c_id; "

Comment: if u did like to increament every seconds, i suggest you use the timer class. using the while loop to count every second is very inacurate and wrong(that is if i understand your question).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a variable and increment it every time in the loop and then check if the variable is even or not. if the variable is even you can use increment your variable $c_id